# How to create object with selective properties?

Tags: c#, powershell

When using Powershell's AD Cmdlets, you can do either of the following to return an object of type Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser:

```
Get-ADUser user
Get-ADUser user -Properties *
```

However, the second will return an object with many more properties.

I'm working on my own PowerShell Cmdlets in C# which will be returning custom objects, similar to this. How do I set it up to only return certain properties based on the arguments?

Here's an example class which would be returned. How would I set it up to sometimes include the Suspended bool, and sometimes not? For instance, only if I have an argument -Suspended

```
public class User
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string GivenName { get; set; }
    public string FamilyName { get; set; }
    public string Uri { get; set; }
    public bool Suspended { get; set; }

    public GAUser(string username, string givenName,
        string familyName)
    {
        Username = username;
        GivenName = givenName;
        FamilyName = familyName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a brief example of using a switch:

```
$scriptBlock = {
 param ([switch]$Suspended)
 $original = New-Object System.Object
 if ($Suspended)
 {
  $original | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Suspended -Value $true
 }
 Write-Output $original
}
```

If you invoke the scriptblock with the Suspended switch, $new will have the property:

```
$new = & $scriptBlock -Suspended
```

If you invoke the scriptblock without the Suspended switch, $new will not have the property:

```
$new = & $scriptBlock
```

Comment: I get what you're saying, and I currently use switches in my code, but I'm looking to do this from a C# standpoint. I've got the switches working, and I have the classes built. I just don't know how to do what you're saying from within C#.